# Ionic Apple push notification signing for development

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, push-notification

This is a 3 part question that I'm asking as one because they're tightly related and 2 of them don't warrant being asked on their own.

I have an app that works and has been successfully installed on an iOS device. I've been able to install it with `ionic run --device` as well as Xcode.

**First Question:**
I've noticed that I have 2 options for signing - "Lee Nathan" and "Lee Nathan (Personal Team)" even though I've only created one certificate. Can someone explain what this means or where I can find more information about it? Google revealed nothing and I don't know enough to know what to search for.

**Second Question:**
I've noticed that if I use Xcode to create an IPA for distribution, I have to use the "Lee Nathan" signing team. If I want to build my app with the Ionic command line, I have to use "Lee Nathan (Personal Team)". I prefer the command line because I can attach live reload and debugging tools to my app. But after adding push notifications I get signing errors when I use the personal team but not the regular team. I am able to install from Xcode to my device and receive push notifications though. How can I use the personal team to continue to run from the command line?
Here are my errors:

- **Failed to create provisioning profile.**
  The app ID "com.example.yadayada" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
- **No profiles for 'com.example.yadayada' were found**
  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.example.yadayada'.

**Third Question (joke):**
The Apple certificate process is ridiculous. Why does Apple hate their developers?